# gc is not working

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I have code like this:

```
D = load_large_amount_of_data()
```

it consume memory within limit

then if I do this:

```
for i in range(10):
    D = load_large_amount_of_data()
```

after few iterations the program will crash with MemoryError

then I try

```
gc.enable()
for i in range(10):
    D = load_large_amount_of_data()
    gc.collect()
```

it still crash with MemoryError

the free memory is becoming less and less during the progress of execution. `gc.collect()` is not helping.

why is this happening? the `D` should be freed when it set to new values right?

P.S.
the `load_large_amount_of_data` is working in a parallel way with `multiprocessing.Pool`

```
def load_large_amount_of_data(total_dir):

    assert os.path.isdir(total_dir)

    fps = ['make file paths']

    # don't worry I have a parallel fs
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    D = pool.map(reader, fps)
    D = np.array(D)

    return D
```

Comment: Have you tried `gc.garbage()` to see what can't be freed?

Comment: You should probably keep a single pool and reuse it, or `close` and `join` the pool when you're done with it if you're going to keep making new ones. You don't seem to be doing any cleanup.

Comment: @user2357112 the pool.close() is working! thank you so much!